# How to make a div fit to the size of the window?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Essentially, i'm trying to emulate the first page of this theme:
http://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-grayscale/

I want to make it so that the first section occupies the entire screen, and clicking the button will scroll down to the other pages on the site (I'll be adding the button later. However, I end up with white space no matter what I do. I tried playing around with the percentage of the div in the css, but it didn't seem to do anything. I just want the black background to extend down to the bottom of the window without a scroll bar, no matter the screen size.

Code can be found here: http://codepen.io/pwatrous/pen/qZeaog

```
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

html {
    height: 100%;
}

h1 {
    margin-top: 0;
    padding-top: 10%;
}

.container-fluid {
    padding: 0px;
}

.section1 {
    background-color: #000000;
    height: 100%
}

.title {
    font-family: Quicksand;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

#name {
    font-size: 5em;
}

#info {
    font-size: 3em;
    padding-bottom: 4%;
}

#bio {
    font-size: 2em;
    padding-bottom: 10%;
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-right: 5%;
}

.fa-chevron-circle-down {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding-bottom: 4%;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try using ViewPorts ?

Comment: any reason you don't just set the background color on the body element to be black?

Answer (score 7):

To make a div fit the entire screen, try this:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}

.my_fullscreen_div {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1:**

Try adding a background-color in the body.

```
body {
background-color:black;
}
```

**Method 2:**

HTML:
place the section2 div inside the section1 div

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="section1 text-center">
        <h1 class="title" id="name">Patrick Watrous</h1>
        <h2 class="title" id="info">Learn. Implement. Innovate.</h2>
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-down fa-5x"></i>
        <p class="title" id="bio">The ability to dream up an idea and then recreate it on a computer has always been something that has caused me immense satisfaction. Due to this, I'm pursuing a bachelor's degree at Northeastern University in computer science and business. I'm interested in all facets of design, from Bootstrap to Java. Take a look at my website and see what i've been up to!</p>
  <div class="section2 text-center">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,.....
  </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm having some trouble understanding what's different in the HTML in method 2. Could you possibly elaborate?

Comment: place the section2 div inside the section1 div