# How do I make a particular section of a webpage take up exactly the area of the user's viewing window?

Tags: html, css

```css
html, body{
  height:100%;
}
.fillheight{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  min-height:100%;
}

.fillheight-2{
    flex:1;
}

/*NAVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVV
VVVVVVVVVVVVV
NAV
NAV
NAV*/
.fixated{
  position:fixed;
}
  * {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  transition-property: all;
  transition-duration: .6s;
  transition-timing-function: ease;
}

.list-style{
  list-style-type: none;
}

.a{
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  color: #938653;
  
  @media (min-width: 100px) {
    font-size: 1em;
  }
  @media (min-width: 600px) {
    font-size: 1.6em;
  }
   @media (min-width: 1000px) {
    font-size: 2.1em;
  }
  
  
 }

.flex{
  background-color: #212121;
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
  justify-content: space-around;
 width: 100%;
  margin: auto 0;
}
/*HOVERRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR
RRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR

RRRRRRRRRRRR
RRRRRRRR*/
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  }

a:hover,
a:active,
a:link {
   color : #938653;
   text-decoration: none;
}

.btn-2 {
    letter-spacing: 0px;
}

.btn-2:hover,
.btn-2:active {
  letter-spacing: 10px;
}

.btn-2:after,
.btn-2:before {
  
  border: 1px solid rgba(#938653, 0);
  bottom: 2px;
  top: 2px;
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 280ms ease-in-out;
  width: 0;
}

.btn-2:hover:after,
.btn-2:hover:before {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  border-color: #938653;
  transition: width 350ms ease-in-out;
  width: 100%;
}

.btn-2:hover:before {
  bottom: auto;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
/*WELCOMEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
WELCOMEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
WELCOMEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
EEEEEEEEEEEEEE
EEEEEEEEEEEEEE*/
 * {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  transition-property: all;
  transition-duration: .6s;
  transition-timing-function: ease;
}

html,body{
  height: 100%;
  background: #4A6556;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: #4A6556;
  
  padding-top:60px;
  height: 100vh;
}

.Hey{
  font-family: 'Kumar One', cursive;
  color: #938653;
  font-size: 38px;
  
  @media (min-width:500px){
    font-size: 70px;
  }

  @media (min-width:800px) {
    font-size:100px;
  }
  
  @media (min-width:1100px) {
    font-size:165px;
  }
}

.Hello{
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  color:#212121;
  font-size: 16px;
  
   @media (min-width:500px){
    font-size: 24px;
  }
  
   @media (min-width:800px) {
    font-size:40px;
  }
  
  @media (min-width:1100px) {
    font-size:58px;
  }
}
/*ABOUT
ABOUTTTTTTTTTTTTTT
ABOUTTTTTTTTTTTT
ABOUTTTTTTTTTT*/

.parent{
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  background:#212121;
  padding-bottom:50px;
}

.general{
  background:#212121;
  border-radius: 7px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.Header{
  order: 1;
  height: 100px;
  flex: 0 1 100%;
  
  color: #4A6556;
  font-family: 'Kumar One', cursive;
  font-size: 80px;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-top:60px;
}

.Main{
  order: 2;
  min-height: 250px;
  flex: 2.5 1;
  @media(max-width: 800px){
   flex:1 1 100%;
   
  }
  
   color: #938653;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 22px;
  padding: 20px 50px;
  }

.Pic{
  order: 4;
  flex: 1 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
  
  padding-right: 55px;
}

.pic{
  text-align: center;
}


/*PROJECTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT
PROJECTTTTTTTTTTTTTT
PROJECTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT
PROJECTTTTTTTTTTTTTT
*/

.Section{
  @media (max-width:600px){
    zoom:90%;
  }
  
   @media (max-width:512px){
    zoom:85%;
  }
  
   @media (max-width:489px){
    zoom:80%;
  }
  @media (max-width:462px){
    zoom:70%;
  }
  @media (max-width:420px){
    zoom:60%;
  }
  
}

.Flexy{

 display: flex;
 flex-flow: row wrap;
 align-items: center;
 align-content: center;
  background: #4A6556;
  padding-bottom:50px;
  padding-top:30px;
}
  
.coloring {
  
  border-radius:7px;
  padding: 5px;
 
  margin: 5px
}

.Projects{
  order: 1;
  flex: 0 1 100%;
  font-family: 'Kumar One', cursive;
  color: #938653;
  font-size: 80px;
  padding-left: 50px;
}

.Tribute{
  order: 2;
  flex: 1 1;
  text-align: center;
  
  font-family: 'Kumar One', cursive;
  color:#212121;
  font-size: 50px;
  
}

.Portfolio{
  order: 3;
  flex: 1 1;
  text-align:center;
  @media (max-width:1120px){
    flex:100%;
  }
  
   font-family: 'Kumar One', cursive;
  color:#212121;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.fade{
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out;
}

.fade:hover {
  opacity: 0.4;
}

.word-1{
  position: relative;
  left: -62px;
  top:26px;  
}

.word-2{
  position: relative;
  left:10px;
  top:23px;
}

/*CONTACTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT
CONTACTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT
CONTACTTTTTTTTTTTTTT
TTTTTTTTTTTTTT
TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT
TTTTTT*/

.marking{
  
  border-radius: 7px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding:0px;
}

.contener{
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-flow: column;


  background:#212121;
  padding-top:40px;
  padding-bottom:40px;
}

.Contact{
  order:1;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 1.0em;
  margin-bottom:50px;
  font-family: 'Kumar One', cursive;
  color:#938653;
  font-size:75px;
  
}

.Email{
  text-align: center;
  order:2;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  color:#4A6556;
  font-size: 50px;
  
}

.Linkedin{
  text-align: center;
  order: 3;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  color:#4A6556;
  font-size:50px;
 
}

.email{
  background:#4A6556;
  color:#938653;
  padding-left:9px;
  padding-right:9px;
  border-radius:6px;
}

//colors
$red: #212121;
$white: red;

//base styles

* {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  transition-property: all;
  transition-duration: .6s;
  transition-timing-function: ease;
}


.btn-3 {
  background: lighten($red, 3%);  
  border: 0px solid darken($red, 1);
  box-shadow: 9px 9px 0 darken($red, 5%), 2px 4px 6px darken($red, 2%);
 
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  transition: all 150ms linear;
  padding:0px;
}

.btn-3:hover {
  background: darken($red, 1.5%);
  border: 0px solid rgba(#000, .05);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px rgba(#fff, 1);
  color: lighten($red, 18%); 
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 0 darken($red, 9.5%);
  transition: all 250ms linear;
  opacity:0.8;
}

.zoomout{
  @media(max-width:760px){
    zoom:80%;
  }
  @media(max-width:580px){
  zoom:70%;
  }
  @media(max-width:580px){
  zoom:60%;
  }
  @media(max-width:430px){
  zoom:50%;
  }
  @media(max-width:430px){
  zoom:50%;
  }
  @media(max-width:430px){
  zoom:40%;
  }  
  
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kumar+One" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kumar+One|Lato" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kumar+One" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kumar+One|Lato" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:700" rel="stylesheet">

<body class="fillheight">
  
  <div class="fillheight-2">
    <ul class="flex fixated list-style">
      
  <li><a href="#" class="btn-2 a">About </a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="btn-2 a">Projects</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="btn-2 a">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
  
  </div>
  <div class="fillheight-2">  
    
    <div class="box">
  
    <hey class="Hey">Welcome!</hey>  
    <hello class="Hello">This is David's portfolio page.</hello>
    
   </div>
   </div>
  
  <div class="fillheight-2">  
    
    <div class="parent">
    <header class="Header general">About</header>
    <main class="Main general">I started learning web development the December of 2016 by completing my first ever coding challenge on Free Code Camp. It was that December because that was when the winter recess of my college began, which meant I had abundance of time to assign to whatever activity I would take up.<br><br>The reason I am interested in web development is that I want to make beautiful and easy-to-use websites for people. I chose websites over apps or softwares that you have to download to use, because they are so accessible and widespread.</main>
    <pic class="pic Pic general"><img src=""http://imgur.com/kJNhW7r"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/kJNhW7r.jpg" title="source: imgur.com"" class="img-circle" alt="My head shot" width="250" height="250"></pic>
  </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="fillheight-2">
    <section class="Flexy Section">

    <div class="coloring Projects ">Projects</div>
   <div class="coloring Tribute">
     <div class="word-1">Tribute Page</div>
      <a href="https://codepen.io/Hello911/pen/EZYWed"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ifkpFbR.png" title="source: imgur.com" class="img-rounded fade" alt="Tribute Page" width="500" height="300"></a>
  </div>
   <div class="coloring Portfolio">
  <div class="word-2">My Portfolio Page</div>
     <a href="#"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/EnR9gj1.png" title="source: imgur.com" title="source: imgur.com" title="source: imgur.com" class="img-rounded fade" alt="Coming Soon!" width="500" height="300"></a>
  </div>
    
</section>
  </div>
  
  <div class="fillheight-2"> <section class="contener">
  <div class="marking Contact">Contact</div>
   <div class="marking Email">Email me <b class="email zoomout">experimentative@gmail.com</b></div>
   <div class="marking Linkedin">Or connect with me on <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/david-c-b8b880101
" class="btn-3 btn" target="_blank"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/7lTSk6J.png" title="source: imgur.com" alt="Linkedin Button" class="img-rounded" height=50px width=50px></a></div></div>
</section>
  
</body>
```

[My project.](http://codepen.io/Hello911/pen/ygOQwp?editors=1100)

I want the first section, the part that says "Welcome!". I want that green rectangular section to take up exactly the space of the window that people are viewing my webpage in. (Of course, excluding the area already taken up by the navigation bar).

I don't know if that makes any sense. But basically, after the web page finish loading itself, the first thing, and the **only** thing that the viewer should see is the navigation bar and the Welcome section. Then the viewer may go to others parts/sections of the page by clicking the buttons in the navigation bar or scrolling down.
[image]

```html
Go to link. Too many lines of code.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a div fit to the size of the window?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37378895/how-to-make-a-div-fit-to-the-size-of-the-window)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use viewport units (`vw` and `vh`). In your case you want to use `100vh` to represent 100% of the viewport height.

```
.box {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so so much. If you don't mind, I want to delete this post. Its kinda getting too many downvotes

Comment: @user132522 no problem. would be great if you can accept my answer as the fix. re: the downvotes, I'm assuming it's because you didn't include relevant code, you just linked to a 3rd party site.

Comment: @user132522 doh! sorry :P

Answer (score 0):

Try using [ViewPort Height](https://web-design-weekly.com/2014/11/18/viewport-units-vw-vh-vmin-vmax/).
Add this to your Hey class:

```
.Hey{
    height:100vh;
}
```

This way your section or div will be 100% of the window size. If you want that the navbar + your section be always 100% of the height, put both on a container that uses `height:100vh;`